# Date.parse is giving Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Here in my dateString I have received this date `"2022-05-11 00:00:00 ADT"` but for that TimeZone it's throwing `Invalid Date` but it's working as expected for EST, PST. May anyone help me here

I just want to know the solution or may be any alternate way of `Date.parse()`

Here is the Code Snippet

```
let userLocalTimeZone = $A.get("$Locale.timezone");
let userLocalTz = new Date(dateData).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: userLocalTimeZone, timeStyle: "long"}).split(" ").slice(-1)[0];
let dateString = dateData + ' 00:00:00 ' + userLocalTz;
let dateTimeValue =Date.parse(dateString);
let utcDatetime = $A.localizationService.formatDateTimeUTC(dateTimeValue);
utcDatetime = $A.localizationService.formatDate(utcDatetime,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't miss `T` between date and time?

Comment: you could try doing a replace on `ADT` for `UTC-0300` before the parse as you know it's 3 hours behind UTC